# Can I create an isolated page in a project with spark masterpage setup?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

Ive got a project that has got an application.spark and a html.spark that contains all the masterpage markup. The views work fine, but I need to create an isolated page that has no relation at all with the masterpages. Is it possible or will I need to have another nested masterpage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/master-layouts using:

```
<use master=""/>
```